# Rotate UILabel On Clockface

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uilabel, uipickerview

Is it possible to rotate UILabels or similar about a clockface?

For example, if I had an array of numbers from one to twelve, it would render as such in a circular manner. However, with a touch event I could move the labels about the face of the clock i.e. I could move 12 in a rightward motion until it reached 6, with all other numbers remaining in their positions.

I have considered UIPicker, but that follows a 'top to bottom' approach. I need a solution to move the label about a point while maintaining the order of the other labels.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a matter of opposing rotation transforms. Rotate the clock face while at the same time rotating all the subview numbers the same amount in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended:**

1 Clock without small & Big handle (As Image) set it in ImageView.

2 Another two image view one for Small hand another one for Big hand.

3 Rotate the hands(UIImageView) by using the below code as you needed.

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

UIImageView *smallHand = set your smallHand image view here;
UIImageView *bigHand = set your bigHand image view here;


// Small hand
CGAffineTransform smallHandTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, (DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1)));

// Big hand
CGAffineTransform bigHandTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, (DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(1*0.60)));


// Apply rotation
smallHand.transform = smallHandTransform;
bigHand.transform = bigHandTransform;
```

I knew that question was rotating the label, if you need it apply this transform on UILabel.

I hope somebody will make use of this idea. Good luck :)

[Here is the example project](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMAnalogClock)